# LTRIM ending values throughout entire column using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column named 'ProjectCode' with all values in the column set up as such:  123.21.000. I am looking to write something to iterate through the whole column and remove the ending .000 from all of the entries. Here is an example of the many things I've tried.

```
select ltrim("Project Code", '.000') 
from "Project Code"
```

Comment: I'm not use what `LTRIM` has to do with this question at all; `LTRIM` removes the leading space characters from the a string. You want to remove a trailing `.000` string.

Comment: was just something i tried..  I really dont know how to write it to remove just those characters through the whole column without removing them one at a time..

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: version 15.0.18404

Comment: Do you want to remove by character, or can you just say remove the last 4 chars ?

Comment: That isn't a valid build of [SQL Server 2019](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/#sql2019x) @Anomaly . The latest build is 15.0.4198.2.

Comment: it would be best to increase the sample size, to undestand better your data

Comment: ahh sorry,  its   14.0.3048.4 (X64)

Comment: Try this `DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(100) = '123.21.000'; 
SELECT CONCAT(PARSENAME(@Str , 3) , '.', PARSENAME(@Str , 2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing such something, but since we don't known enough of your data we can only guess

Here are a few posibilities

```
declare @t table (ProjectCode varchar(50))
insert into @t values ('123.21.000'), ('000123.21.000')

select ProjectCode,
       -- just remove the last 3 chars, whatever they are
       left(ProjectCode, len(ProjectCode) - 3) as [3 last removed],
        
       -- another way of removing the last 3 chars
       substring(ProjectCode, 1, len(ProjectCode) - 3) as [3 last removed substr],
       
       -- remove all '0' chars, both left and right from the value
       trim('0' from ProjectCode) as [trim all zeros],            
       
       -- replace any occurence of '000' by ''
       replace(ProjectCode, '000', '') as [replace 000]             
from @t
```

This returns

| ProjectCode | 3 last removed | 3 last removed substr | trim all zeros | replace 000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123.21.000 | 123.21. | 123.21. | 123.21. | 123.21. |
| 000123.21.000 | 000123.21. | 000123.21. | 123.21. | 123.21. |

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a fully supported version of SQL Server you could use `TRIM`:

```sql
SELECT TRIM('0.' FROM ProjectCode) AS ProjectCode
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

This *assumes* that your column `ProjectCode` doesn't have leading `0`s or `.`'s (i.e. `'00.123.000'` or `'0123.456.1'`).

Comment: I think trim (and the variants) are a red herring used by OP without any useful purpose.

Comment: @SMor I already stated that `LTRIM` made no sense in the questions comments, however, that doesn't change my answer here; `TRIM` would work here for what it appears the OP wants.

Comment: ill give that a shot too,   yes there are no 0s in the front of any of the code numbers,  and every one of them has .000 at the end.

Comment: @Larnu **and the variants**. It appears that OP wants to remove the ending ".000" as best I can tell. There are no spaces to trim.

Comment: @SMor notice `'0.' FROM`. `TRIM`, here, isn't looking for spaces at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PARSENAME` function to get the first two values in the string:

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(100) = '123.21.000'; 
SELECT CONCAT(PARSENAME(@Str , 3) , '.', PARSENAME(@Str , 2))

Result:   123.21
```

Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(PARSENAME("Project Code" , 3) , '.', PARSENAME("Project Code" , 2))
FROM "Project Code"
```

But if you have variable number of `'.'` and you only want to get rid of the very last . and any value after that, then you can use the following query:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Col VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO @t (Col)
VALUES ('123.21.000') , ('123.21.01.000'), ('123.00.011.0111.0000'), ('123'); 


SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Col) , CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Col)) + 1 , LEN(Col)))
FROM @t

Result: 
123.21
123.21.01
123.00.011.0111
123
```